# What is the best way to 'ping' a database via JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to determine the best way to ping a database via JDBC. By 'best' I mean fast and low overhead. For example, I've considered executing this:

```
"SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
```

but I believe the DUAL table is Oracle-specific, and I need something more generic.

Note that `Connection` has an `isClosed()` method, but the javadoc states that this cannot be used to test the validity of the connection.

Comment: (I used `SELECT @@VERSION` on MS SQL Server, but that isn't even SQL.)

Comment: On MSSQL the Microsoft JDBC driver uses `SELECT 1` for validation. (https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java#L5583)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that would be Oracle-only, but there is no generic way to do this in JDBC.

Most connection pool implementations have a configuration parameter where you can specify the SQL that will be used for ping, thus pushing the responsiblity to figure out how to do it to the user.

That seems like the best approach unless someone comes up with a little helper tool for this (of course, it precludes using potentially even faster non-SQL-based methods like [Oracle's internal ping function](http://www.orindasoft.com/public/Oracle_JDBC_JavaDoc/javadoc1110/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#pingDatabase()))

Comment: See my answer, JDBC 4 has a generic way (of cause not all drivers offer JDBC 4 yet).

Answer (score 16):

With JDBC 4 you can use `isValid(int)` ([JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid%28int%29)) from the Connection Interface. This basically does the trial statement for you.

Some driver implement this by sending the correct dummy SQL to the database and some directly uses low level operations which reduces the parsing overhead.

However beware of the timeout, some drivers (DB/400 and Oracle Thin) do spawn a new time thread for each invocation, which is not really acceptable for most Pool validation scenarios). And Oracle also does not seem to use a prepared statement, so it’s kind of relying on the implicit cache.

Answer (score 6):

MySQL has a nice mechanism, documented in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5446031/152061). From the answer:

> ```
> "/* ping */ SELECT 1"
> ```
>
> This will actually cause the driver send a ping to the server and return a fake, light-weight, result set.

Having said that, [@eckes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12208137/152061) is the best (using JDBC 4's `Connection.isValid(int)`).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a generic solution, either. For IBM's UDB on iSeries (and perhaps other DB2 systems) it would be

```
select 1 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Comment: The AS400JDBCConnection.isValid for the java8/jdbc40 Version of jtopen uses by the way an internal function and no SQL string to parse, it’s therefore more efficient (as long as you do not specify a timeout since that would spawn a timer thread) https://sourceforge.net/p/jt400/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk/jdbc40/com/ibm/as400/access/AS400JDBCConnection.java

Answer (score 2):

You could try to get the db name from the connection meta data and execute a matching sql staement. E.g.

```
Connection con = null;
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
  con = dataSource.getConnection();
  String dbProductName = con.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName();
  Statement st = con.createStatement();
  if ( "PostgreSQL".equalsIgnoreCase(dbProductName) ) {
    rs = st.executeQuery("select version();");
  } else if ( "Oracle".equalsIgnoreCase(dbProductName) ) {
    rs = st.executeQuery("select 1 from dual");
  } else {
   ...
  }
} catch ( Exception ex ) {
  System.out.prinln("DB not reachable");
} finally {
   // close statement, connection etc.
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be out to lunch on this one, but could you simply execute some non-sense query, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM donkey_giraffe_87
```

I don't know very much about JDBC's error handling, but perhaps you could check to see if the database is at least telling you that the table does not exist. If JDBC's error codes are vendor-specific, the Spring Framework has some utilities for mapping these codes to more meaningful exceptions.

Comment: It could be expensive to try to query a non-exisiting table. Dictionary cache misses and error handling code.