# Ping MySQL Server Using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ping

This seems rather simple (not for me)...

How does one ping a mysql server using the JDBC? i have successfully used select and insert queries with JDBC and MySQL, but how to ping???

TIA

Comment: If you don’t know how to do it, how do you it’s simple?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The MySQL JDBC driver (Connector/J) provides a ping mechanism.

If you do a SQL query prepended with `/* ping */` such as:

```
"/* ping */ SELECT 1"
```

This will actually cause the driver send a ping to the server and return a fake, light-weight, result set.

(You can find this buried fairly deep in the [Connector/J documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html#idm139975764832048); search for "ping" on that page.  Read it carefully: this mechanism is *very sensitive* to the syntax used.  Unlike most SQL, the "parsing" of the "ping" marker happens in the client-side JDBC driver itself.).

Comment: +1. It would be good to know what makes this "lightweight" in comparison to a simple `SELECT 1`. I couldn't find anything on that page that documents how much "lighter" the ping is

Comment: thanks alot... i just wanted to know, dont you have to enter a username and that user's password in order to ping? i shouldve stated this earlier... sorry...
i'm trying to ping without a username and password... basically checking if mysql is present and that the settings lead to an mysql server... i.e: port 3306 and the host (im just using 127.0.0.1 for now)... thanks in advance G6

Comment: Yes. Since you're using a function of the database, you need a connection, which requires a login.

Comment: Is the SELECT 1 required? The docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-en/connector-j-usagenotes-tomcat.html mention "Note that Connector/J 5.1.3 introduced a facility whereby, rather than use a validationQuery value of SELECT 1, it is possible to use validationQuery with a value set to /* ping */."

Comment: ^ Yes, the above documentation contradicts the other documentation on the subject, stating that it must "exactly" be /* ping \*/ as opposed to just "starting" with it: "Note that /* ping */ has to be specified exactly." What is the deal?

Comment: To hazard a *guess* to my question, this page (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html#idm47534937957872) appears to give a snippet of the Connector/J source code, and if it does, it would mean "starts with" as opposed to "exactly" as the requirement. If that's the case, the documentation for Tomcat in my previous comment would be technically incorrect in its specification of "exactly". But it would be nice not to resort to educated guesses here.

Comment: what makes ping more efficient, as compared to SELECT 1, is server side processing (parsing statement, creating and sending result set medata , even SELECT 1 would do that). The cheapest SQL command is not SELECT 1 though. It is  "DO 1"  -it saves some time as it does not send result set. you'd need statement.executeUpdate("DO 1")

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is anything in the JDBC APi for this.

But you can simply use InetAddress and the isReachable() method to check if the server is there (which is essentially what a ping is doing).

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29

**Edit**:
If you want to check if MySQL is running rather than pinging the server you could try to open a socket to the server on the MySQL default port.

Something like this:

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("your.server.com");
int port = 3306;
SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, port);
Socket sock = new Socket();
sock.connect(sockaddr, 2000); // open the connection with a 2 seconds timeout
```

If connect() does not throw an exception something is running on port 3306.

If you want to make sure that it's a MySQL server on that port, the only way is to establish a JDBC connection (but you need a valid username/password for that) and run a statement e.g. the PING statement mentioned by Brian.

Comment: This won't check db presence on the host.

Comment: @Piotr Findeisen: You said you wanted to ping the server, so I assumed you wanted to make sure the server itself is reachable.

Comment: I don't know what questioner wants :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this in JDBC by you can use Connection Pooling to validate your connection like so (This is the `context.xml` for Tomcat (found in the `META-INF` directory of your application)):

```
<Resource name="jdbc/My_DS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
            username="USERNAME" password="PASSWORD" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYDB?autoReconnect=true" 
            removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true"
            testOnBorrow="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1" />
```

The `validationQuery` validates if the connection is successful or not.

Comment: Perhaps validationQuery="/* ping */ SELECT 1" would work better?