# MyBatis DB connection fail-over mechanism is not working

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, aem, mybatis, osgi-bundle

I have a java application (jar) installed as OSGI bundle in Adobe experience manager.

In Java application I have following Datasource configuration :
    1. I am using MyBatis-3 to manage Datasource pooled connections in following manned :
            
              
              
              
              
            
            Using the properties as mentioned in http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html

```
2.  Creating SQL Session factory in following manner :
       SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(configuration);

3. Using SQL Server 2014 as my database.
```

We have cluster of DB Servers, whenever we have to apply a patch to Database, we switch the DB server.
Even though dataSource URL remains same, application results in DB connection failure errors.
Issue gets resolved only after bundle restard.
Is there any way that connection pool can auto reconnect or recover?
I am new to MyBatis, SQL server and AEM, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I assume with your cold standby approach, all already opened database connections will fail. Sorry, I don't know MyBatis. But either you find a better clustering approach, or you should have ConnectionPool with verification. That means that the ConnectionPool makes a extreme simple query, before handing out the connection. If this fails, this faulty connection gets dropped and a new one is opened. Someone else asked for it too, but didn't got an answer here: http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/Connection-is-invalid-how-to-check-for-this-and-get-a-valid-connection-td4026961.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple workaround for you, is to setup a pool-ping-query. It seems, that your connections don't survive the switch to the cold standby database. They have to re-opened. With this query the connection pool can check, if a connection is still ok. If not, this faulty connection will be closed.

After giving my comment, I looked at http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html. There you should look for the parameters

- **poolPingQuery**
- **poolPingEnabled**

I would try it with the following configuration

```
<dataSource type="POOLED">
   ...
   <property name="poolPingQuery" value="/* ping */ SELECT 1"/>
   <property name="poolPingEnabled" value="true"/>
</dataSource>
```

But be aware, that this is still not a graceful switch. It only checks for connections in the pool. All your running transactions will still get an error. But it might be ok, if your transactions are short, not massively parallel, and not highly critical.

Comment: Thank you for quick turnaround, I read about poolPingQuery but I didn't find that it can be used to reestablish the connections. Is there any way we can to a graceful switch to avoid any error for ongoing user sessions?

Comment: I think, this will not work with your Active/Passive SQL server cluster. You would need a phase, with both nodes Active. In this Active/Active phase, you must gracefully switch all connections. 
If Failover is that important, then maybe you have to give up connection pooling. This might makes some things better. But performance will suffer.

Comment: I looked at the SQL server docs. It says "When a failover occurs, the virtual network name (VNN) is registered to the new active node after it starts. This process is transparent **to the client or application connecting** to SQL Server and this **minimize the downtime** the application or clients experience during a failure."
So the fail-over works only for **new** connections. I afraid, you have to test carefully how the SQL cluster behaves. Eventually the "Select 1" still works, even if the connected node is NOT Active anymore.

Comment: So in this case can I go with "/* ping */ SELECT 1"  instead of "SELECT 1" as advised in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982281/mysql-connection-validity-test-in-datasource-select-1-or-something-better