# Ping Database Utility

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jdbc

Does anyone know if there is a database connection testing utility or database ping utility available?  Or is there a JRE component that has certain commands to ping database connections?

Our Java servlet connects to `Oracle` and `SQL` server databases.  We can easily check the connections are okay on development machines as they have Eclipse installed and are within our Firewall.  But our Live servlet server is outside the `Firewall` and we cannot install `Eclipse` on that machine.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: these might be helpful to you 
1.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569956/ping-a-mysql-server)
2.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847246/what-is-the-best-way-to-ping-a-database-via-jdbc)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the comment of Learner (+1).
However, **it is better to configure the application server in order to test the connection periodically and reconnect if down**.