# How to test if an OracleConnection is "not Connected to Oracle"?

Tags: .net, windows, oracle, odp.net

We are writing a Service that waits on an Oracle Queue via ODP.Net.  We are trying to best handle session or network interruptions.

The wait on the queue will return "EOF on communication channel" if I kill the session, from that point all attempts to use the connection give "Not connected to Oracle" exceptions.

Is there a simple way to test if the connection would give "Not connected to Oracle" if it were used?  NOTE: (theConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open) is coming back true even though the connection is not connected to Oracle.

Thanks in advance -

sh-

Comment: Run `select * from dual` query and check if it throws any exceptions.

Comment: ok - good suggestion.  Do you know if this has been shown to be the most efficient way to do this?  We are operating in a tight loop that will be doing this regularly and it will return success 99.9+% of the time, so doing it efficiently is important.

Comment: Most connection pool implementations use that method to "ping" the database using some simple query to check if the connection is still alive, and if not - to invalidate the connection and reconnect. Another ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847246/what-is-the-best-way-to-ping-a-database-via-jdbc - you can retrieve some database metadata using standard API, if the connection is broken, then the call throws an error.

Comment: The ODP.NET connection pool itself will do a SELECT SYSDATE from DUAL if you turn on the validate connection connection string option. Have you considered letting the connection pool do the work for you?

Comment: I'm not using connection pooling because I always have an active session that is waiting on an Oracle queue (this is system service).  If the session is lost then this wait usually returns "EOF on communication channel".   I guess I could just close the connection whenever I get EOF and re-open it at the top of my processing loop if it is closed.  I think I have just answered my own question - amazing what a good night's sleep will do for you.

Comment: RE: which query to use to "ping".  I will do some experiments to see which simple query will return most quickly (as a proxy for least load on the database).

Comment: OK - did some experiments.  These tests:
1. select * from dual using ExecuteScalar
2. select * from dual using ExecuteNonQuery
3. select sysdate from dual using ExecuteScalar
4. select sysdate from dual using ExecuteNonQuery

I did 1000 iterations of each and ran them 4 times.

RESULT: they are all about the same.  On my system about 8.5 iterations per sec.

I expect the database performance is by far the most determining factor so using ExecuteScalar or ExecuteNonQuery (or even ExecuteReader) will probably not affect the performance.

I also tried "select 0 from dual" with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to make my last comment the answer.  If someone has an better alternative I would love to hear it.

I performed these tests to determine the least expensive 'ping'-query:

1. select * from dual using ExecuteScalar
2. select * from dual using ExecuteNonQuery
3. select sysdate from dual using ExecuteScalar
4. select sysdate from dual using ExecuteNonQuery

I did 1000 iterations of each and ran them 4 times.

RESULT: they are all about the same. On my system about 8.5 iterations per sec (which sucks). I expect the database performance is by far the most determining factor so using ExecuteScalar or ExecuteNonQuery (or even ExecuteReader) will probably not affect the performance.

I also tried "select 0 from dual" with the same results.

Comment: You could also try to execute: begin null end; or something similar. I have not tried it myself.